# Blender axis at an angle

Tags: axis

For some reason when I try to move an object along the Y-axis, it moves at an angle. It's best to see the photo for the explanations.[image]

Answer (score 1):

You most likely changed the transform orientations. Change it back to "global".

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Is there a shortcut to change it?

Comment: "," (dot from the main keyboard part) then radial menu.